# How to support different jquery-ui themes

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am making a calendar component in jQuery which I want to be styleable with theme-roller themes and any of the available jquery themes (smoothness, ui-ligtness, ui-darkness etc.). Using the different css classes ui-widget, ui-widget-container, ui-state-XXX I have something that works ok. The problem is that the background for some of the themes ends up looking weird because of the backgrounds position.

An sample is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ddn3t/1

However, note that I can't realy use `background-postion: bottom` since if I change the theme I would need to alter that value to `top` instead.

For instance in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/Uasen/2

So I need a way to have the background be positioned properly for both cases.

Comment: Themeroller is a developer tool, you really shouldn't expose it to users.

Comment: @Andrew I do not intend to expose users to it. I want to be able to give other developers an easy way of styling the calendar component (built using jquery-ui widget factory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state classes are for *clickable button-like elements*, not really for anything else. They are the issue. If you remove them then everything will display fine. You probably should also add the ui-widget class to the outer element. ie.

```
<div style="height: 400px;" class="ui-calendar-day ui-widget ui-widget-content">
<div class="ui-calendar-day-name ui-calendar-day-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix " style="top: 0px; ">Friday</div>
<div style="display: none" class="ui-calendar-day-number ui-calendar-day-header ui-widget-header" style="top: 0px; ">7</div>
```

​

@see [Theme API](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API)